# ¿como elimino java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 es este codigo?

Tags: java, excepciones

```
while ((ln2 = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] par = ln2.split(";");
            arbol mon = new arbol(par[0], par[1], par[2], Integer.parseInt(par[3]), Float.parseFloat(par[4]), Float.parseFloat(par[5]));
            areant.addElement(mon);
       }
```

esta es la linea con el error:

```
arbol mon = new arbol(par[0], par[1], par[2], Integer.parseInt(par[3]), Float.parseFloat(par[4]), Float.parseFloat(par[5]));
```

Comment: Bienvenido , recuerda revisar [ask] y realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento bàsico, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a que al leer el array de elementos tipo String no puedes asegurar que se obtengan los 6 valores en todos los casos

```
  String[] par = ln2.split(";");
  arbol mon = new arbol(par[0], par[1], par[2], Integer.parseInt(par[3]), Float.parseFloat(par[4]), Float.parseFloat(par[5]));
```

Puedes usar un mètodo para validar si existe o no el valor en el array:

```
public static boolean existsValue(String[] array, int index) {
    boolean result = false;
        try{
           String valor =  array[index];
           result = true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
    return result;
}
```

de esta forma llamarìas el mètodo definiendo un valor default si es que no se encuentra en el array:

```
 String[] par = ln2.split(";");
 arbol mon = new arbol(existsValue(par, 0)?par[0]:"", existsValue(par, 1)?par[1]:"", existsValue(par, 2)?par[2]:"", Integer.parseInt(existsValue(par, 3)?par[3],"0"), Float.parseFloat(existsValue(par, 4)?par[4],"0"), Float.parseFloat(existsValue(par, 5)?par[5]:"0"));
```

Comment: gracias.........